# ROS getPath() command problematic when using ROS as a stand alone library

Tags: c++, ros

As the title mentions, I am using ROS as a stand-alone library in C++.
That means I import ROS as a lib and catkin is not used.

Now, I want to read a .yaml config file. One would expect this to work:
`std::string pkg_loc = ros::package::getPath("sample_name");`

It just seems to be problematic with ROS being used as a lib.
Directions to add catkin-related lines to my CMAKE file don't work and I keep getting this error:
`error while loading shared libraries: librospack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Any ideas on a better way for me to do this?

Things I've tried so far:

- I did include `roslib` in my `set(ROS_LIBS ...)` line of CMAKE.
- I have this in my .bashrc `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib`
- I do of course have `#include <ros/package.h>`

I'm using ROS Noetic, CMAKE 3.16, Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Please share how your CMakeLists.txt look like. It seems you have not linked the library using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Thank you, I did do that but forgot to add that detail. Thank you... so I have ${ROS_LIBS} in target_link_libraries and also PRIVATE ${ROS_LIB_DIR}) in taget_link_libaries and PRIVATE ${ROS_INCLUDE_DIR} in target_include_directores ... the ROS lib works, it's just this getPath() function that is giving me trouble.

Comment: Do you get that error during compilation or during run?

Comment: I get it during run, builds fine.

Comment: Do `ldd <executable-file-name>` and check what output you get. Do you see something like "not found"?